# How to get textarea rows count in html using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, textarea

Is it possible to get `textarea row count` in html using `angularjs`?

Below is `javascript` way to get the row count.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('field_id').rows)
```

The code below doesn't work but something similar to it, just using front-end?

```
{{mainCtrl.header.modelName.rows}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are two types of textarea row count you can fetch using angularjs :

1. Fixed rows - that are pre defined for the textarea element
2. Dynamic rows - that can change as per the new lines added to the textarea element.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.fixedRows = angular.element(document.querySelector("#txt-area")).attr("rows");

  $scope.getDynamicRows = function() {
    var ele = angular.element(document.querySelector("#txt-area"));
    return ele.val().split(/\r|\r\n|\n/).length;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <textarea id="txt-area" rows="10" cols="50" type="text" ng-model="textValue"></textarea>
  <p>Fixed Rows Count = {{fixedRows}}, Dynamic Rows Count = {{getDynamicRows()}}
   </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why add a jQuery dependency?

Comment: I removed it but had to update the `angular.element` to expect `document.querySelector("#txt-area")` rather than using the element reference directly.